# Issues in linux shell script when converting pre and post epoch dates to another format using date -d

Tags: linux, shell, date

I'm encountering a big problem when converting dates using date -d in a shell script on linux.

My input data is an excel file converted to csv and I'm interested in the date column which is in date format matching %b-%y. I.E.

```
Jan-97
Feb-98
Mar-99
```

etc.

My issue is when encountering dates pre-epoch in this format. I.E.

```
Jan-66
Feb-67
Mar-68
```

I am converting to %Y-%m-%d format with the code below.

```
while read line
do
  mydate=$(grep -Po '[\w]+-[0-9]+' <<< "$line") # gets jan-08
   if [[ ! -z "$mydate" ]]; then #in case there is date to process
     newtempdate=$(echo 01-"$mydate") # converts to 01-jan-08
     newdate=$(date -d "$newtempdate" "+%Y-%m-%d") # converts to 2013-08-01
     sed -i "s#$mydate#$newdate#" inputfile.csv # replaces in the text (-i option)
   fi
done < inputfile.csv
```

The result, using the above examples is:

```
2066-01-01
2067-02-01
2068-03-01
1997-01-01
1998-02-01
1999-03-01
```

As you can see, it's not handling epoch dates correctly, as it's converting them to 21st century dates instead of handling the century properly.

My desire is to find something that strictly converts

```
%b-%y to %Y-%m-%d
```

I don't seem to have the ability to set the input format using "date" so I can't tell it to handle the epoch change correctly.

I'm hoping to use something that will allow me to parse an input file and spit out an output file, or modify an existing file like above so that I can use it in my batch shell script.

It's not possible to manually modify the excel document to change the column formatting as I need the process to be automated, unless there is a way to automate this (not that I've found so far).

Any ideas?

Comment: If you just need it for your excel file, there could be a workaround.. by just testing the int(year) if it is higher than this year (15), then replace it with the previous century year.. for example, jan-75 --> 75>15 => make it jan-1975 and continue...   do you need a working example ?

Comment: Well, the end result is that the data is being converted from excel so that I can load it into a mysql database. Hence why going through the csv conversion.
If I can sanitise it before it goes into the database, it makes life much easier

Comment: By the way, your code works perfectly on my machine... I don't receive 2075.. I just receive 1975... I tried it with string input from shell , and I don't have your csv

Comment: Can you upload your csv somewhere so I could download it and try your code on the CSV file ???

Comment: Data before conversion:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/i9hx3ovnop04j96/databefore.csv?dl=0

data after conversion:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/wopw9g2f0e2kbzw/dataafter.csv?dl=0

Comment: When I use your fail, I get an error for the problematic dates... (`date: invalid date ‘01-Jul-68’`) ... Weird !!! The errors are for the dates before 1969.... after 1969, your code works perfectly

Comment: Please check the output on my system... http://pastebin.com/Pjg8WHy3

Comment: On my System, very simply, `date -d"01-Dec-68" "+%Y-%m"` gives `date: invalid date ‘01-Dec-68’` ... whereas, `date -d"01-Dec-69" "+%Y-%m"` gives correctly `1969-12`

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is still something related to the epoch issue. I just don't know how to fix it :(

Comment: This is what I get for example:

    `[root@localhost data]# date -d "01-Jan-12" "+%Y-%m-%d"
    2012-01-01
    [root@localhost data]# date -d "01-Jan-68" "+%Y-%m-%d"
    2068-01-01`

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so it looks like It's not possible to determine the century of a two digit year progammatically, despite it being easy to do in our minds.

I'm going to have to take it a step backwards and get my source data into a four digit year format instead.

Comment: U are practically right on this solution.. just change the date format for the column in excel (to four digit year), then export it to csv, finally, execute your code... :)